# selecting unique combination from a many to many relationship MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I have a database which has a many to many structure between products and their location in our warehouse (due to the random nature of the products being bought)

I need to match a unique location for the same product to multiple customers who order it.

DB SCHEMA
2 tables

Customer:Cust_ID, Prod_ID

Product:Prod_ID,Locat_ID

There are many locations for the same product and many products in the same location.

Customer:

C1,P1

C2,P1

Product:

P1,L1

P1,L2

P1,L3

```
SELECT
Customer.Cust_ID,
Customer.Prod_ID,
Product.Locat_ID,
FROM Customer  JOIN Product ON Customer.Prod_ID = Location.Prod_ID
```

Gives

C1,P1,L1

C1,P1,L2

C1,P1,L3

C2,P1,L1

C2,P1,L2

C2,P1,L3

If I group by Cust_ID I get

C1,P1,L1

C2,P1,L1

but I need

C1,P1,L1

C2,P1,L2

Thanks for any insights

Comment: how about `select distinct blah blah blah`. Often times people generate the equivalent of a select distinct by using group by without aggregate functions, but that is not very obvious to the casual observer

Comment: distinct only works on the entire row. I need customers to be distinct separately from locations being distinct, not distinct (customer,location) pairs

Comment: I guess if we were given a (dare I say) proper setup of table schema, sample data, and desired results (ignoring completely what you wrote), we would be set to answer this

Comment: Worked out a way. Add the query to a table with a Cust_ID unique key and a Locat_ID unique key and then trapping out the 1062 duplicate key error that is generated on lines 2,3,4 and 6 of the data

Comment: good job, glad to hear it Ellis

Comment: Re "but I need", why? Why should C1 get paired with L1 and C2 with L2 and not the other way around or some other arrangement?

Comment: It doesn't matter which pairing is returned as long as each customer gets a different location. I cannot give the one unit in a given location to two different customers . So ((C1,L3), (C2,L1)) or ((C1,L2),(C2,L3)) would satisfy the requirements but ((C1,L2),(C2,L2)) or ((C1,L3),(C2,L3)) would not!